# Magento remove Option from Bundle product

Tags: php, magento, bundle

I want to remove all options from bundle product programatically, I know only SKU of the product.

I have

```
$bundled = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',THISISMYSKU);

$selectionCollection = $bundled->getTypeInstance(true)->getSelectionsCollection(
            $bundled->getTypeInstance(true)->getOptionsIds($bundled), $bundled);
            foreach($selectionCollection as $option)
            {

                $sku = $option->getSku();
                if($sku !=  "")
                {
                    $optionModel = Mage::getModel('bundle/option');
                    $optionModel->setId($option->option_id);
                    $optionModel->delete();
                    echo 'deleted: '.$option->getName()." optionID(".$option->option_id.")";
                };
```

But if i have it in loop, doesn't work properly, deleting option of other products.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                     ->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_set_id', 4)
                     ->addAttributeToFilter( 'sku', array( 'in' => array( 'my-sku1', 'my-sku2', 'my-sku3' ) ) )
                     ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id','bundle')
                     ->addFieldToFilter('status', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED);

    foreach($productCollection as $product)
    {               
        $bundled = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
        $bundled->load($product->getId());

        $selectionCollection = $bundled->getTypeInstance(true)->getSelectionsCollection(
        $bundled->getTypeInstance(true)->getOptionsIds($bundled), $bundled);

        foreach($selectionCollection as $option)
        {

            $optionModel = Mage::getModel('bundle/option');
            $optionModel->setId($option->option_id);
            $optionModel->delete();

        }

    }
```

hope this help you

Comment: Why do you have to call `$bundled->load($product->getId());` when you already have `$product` instance from `foreach`. Aren't those 2 the same?

Comment: hi this is not deleting an empty options, but only options with selections, is here way to remove emmpty options too?

Answer (score 1):

I recently needed to clear all the options from my product to update it with new options.

I think the simplest way would be this:

```
$product->getTypeInstance()->getOptionsCollection($product)->walk('delete');
$product->save();
```